# Inserting parameter inside HQL and fetch result using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a Employee class mapped to Employee table

```
public Class Employee {

  int id;

  String name;

}
```

i have written a hql query to fetch Employee from various parameters..like

```
Select x from Employee x where x.id = (:id) and x.name = (:name);
```

I have create a map with key as id and name and values as below:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("id", 1);
params.put("name", "Testname");
```

How to make a request in Spring Boot and with a hql query populated with values in Map `params` and fetch a list of Employee objects.

Edit: actually, I want to insert params Map with key and values in the HQL and get result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re set on using HQL queries, this thread should be able to help you.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894691/using-hql-queries-in-spring-boot)

There are also a couple ways to do this that better utilize the power of Spring and JpaRepository. The first is to declare a method in your repository that includes your variable names and use that method in your service:

Repository

```
@Repository
Public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Employee findByIdAndName(int id, String name);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
Public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepo;

    public Employee findByIdAndName(int id, String name) {
        return empRepo.findByIdAndName(id, name);
    }
}
```

This is great if you only have one or two criteria, but more than that and the method name starts to get rather long. The other suggestion is to use Specifications. To use these, you need to also extend JpaSpecificationExecutor in your repo. You can create a separate class to house your specifications, but for this example I’m going to put it in the service.

Repository

```
@Repository
Public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {}
```

Service

```
@Service
Public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepo;

    public Employee findByIdAndName(int id, String name) {
        return empRepo.find(idEquals(id).and(nameEquals(name)));
    }

    private Specification<Employee> idEquals(int id) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(Employee_.id), id);
    }

    private Specification<Employee> nameEquals(String name) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(Employee_.name), name);
    }

}
```

Note that to use the static metamodel Employee_ you will need extra dependencies, specifically org.hibernate.jpamodelgen if memory serves.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use Spring JPA

```
      @Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.id = :id AND e.name = :name")
    List<Employee> findEmployeesByIdAndName(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name);

}
```

Comment: no..I know this ..actually, I want to insert params Map with key and values in the HQL and get result